# JavaFX layout equivalent to GridLayout

Tags: java, layout, javafx

I'm used to working with Swing to create GUIs but for a recent project I've chosen to switch to JavaFX. I'm having some trouble with recreating a certain layout I used to make using a GridLayout.

I desire the following behavior:
2 columns that scale proportionally with the size of their parent that center their contents.

Using Swing, I would make JPanel with a GridLayout (1 row, 2 columns) and add 2 JPanels with a BorderLayout, adding the actual content to those panels with the centered constraint.
Then I could add the first panel to any container that has a layout that stretches with the frame and all would be well.

I seem to be unable to recreate this behavior in JavaFX in a simple way. I can think of ways to do it using bindings and combining several panes but I was hoping there is a layout that does this automatically. I've tried using TilePane, HBox, GridPane, AnchorPane, SplitPane and even BorderPane but none of them seem to do what I want them to.

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this? I would much prefer not to embed Swing into the application. Basically what I want is to be able to split the content into two columns that automatically stretch with the Stage/Scene (JFrame).

Comment: MigLayout has been ported to JavaFX 2 http://www.miglayout.com/
Maybe it can be a solution?

Comment: Have you tried SplitPane?

Comment: Yes, @brano88, but if I disable the divider the contents are disabled too, unless you know how I can lock the divider without disabling the SplitPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridPane? Some references here

- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG
- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: I read the part on percentual width for columns, which helped. However, is this the right way to do it? I feel like I'm manipulating the GridPane to do what I want rather than using something made to do it. Thanks anyway, this solution will do for now!